# FB.Canvas.setSize() not works

Tags: facebook, resize

Resizing app frame does not work for me.

Here is piece of my code:

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : xxx
    channelUrl : '//channel.html',
    status     : true,
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true
  });

  FB.Canvas.setSize({height: 8000});
 }
```

Unfortunately, setSize do nothing. My canvas has still a initial height. 
In app settings i have:
Canvas Height: Fixed at 800px.

Comment: You don't close the fbAsyncInit in the above code. In your app? Also 8000px it's too much, check for any restrictions.

Comment: I edited my question. Now fbAsyncInit is closed.
8000 is only example value. I tried other (lower values) and them does not work too.

Comment: In your App Settings? what options you have setup there?

Comment: Migrations: all disabled, 
Canvas Height: Fixed at 800px

Comment: A guess: try setting both width and height ( `FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810, height: 1200 });` ).

Comment: In documentation i found:
"Note: this method is only enabled when Canvas Height is set to "Settable (Default: 800px)" in the App Dashboard."

But i have no "Settable" option (only fluid and fixed). Maybe, this is the problem?

Comment: hmmm.. problem exists only when I include prototype.js :/